# ajax call to Jetpack subscribe from Magento with Fishpig wp_integration

Tags: wordpress, magento, jetpack, fishpig

**How can I send a request to the Wordpress index.php from Magento with Fishpig Wordpress Integration?**

I have Magento CE set up with Fishpig Wordpress Integration. The blog is properly integrated into Magento with the Fishpig extension. Wordpress is installed in the magento_root/wp directory. My "Wordpress Address" is http://site.localhost/wp. My "Site Address" is "http://site.localhost/blog".

I am trying to replicate the Jetpack subscribe sidebar widget in the sidebar of the Magento page with the blog but have not been able to find the correct url to send the request to. With Worpress + Jetpack and no Magento integration, the request is sent to "http://site.localhost/wp" and the request object looks like:

```
[email] => me@example.com
[action] => subscribe
[source] => http://site.localhost/wp/
[sub-type] => widget
[redirect_fragment] => blog_subscription-2
[_wpnonce] => ab277d6d6f
[jetpack_subscriptions_widget] => Subscribe
```

I have tried using both http://site.localhost/blog/index.php and http://site.localhost/wp/index.php as my request url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by:

1. Creating a Magento "Subscribe" controller - I copied `app/code/community/Fishpig/Wordpress` to `app/code/local/Fishpig/Wordpress/` and created `app/code/local/Fishpig/Wordpress/controllers/SubscribeController.php`
2. Creating a `subscribeAction()` method within `SubscribeController.php`. The `subscribeAction()` method uses `makeHttpPostRequest($url, array $data = array())` that is included in the Fishpig/Wordpress module in `Helper/System.php`
3. Making an ajax request from the Magento subscribe block template to the subscribe controller.

Comment: I need to do it as a API. can u help me how u done this.